# Android button onclick to SQL database Timestamp of different column

Tags: android, sql, timestamp

I have a SQL database that consist of 2 column of TIMESTAMP (Timein and Timeout). Is there any way that when i click a LOGIN button in my app, it will stamp only one of the column(timein), leaving the (timeout) column empty? And when i click on the LOGOUT button, it will leave the column(timein) empty and stamp only the (timeout) column?

Comment: Why not? The simplest way I could think of is have 2 methods to do the necessary insertion (on login) and update (on logout). So `insertRow(String timeIn)` and `updateRow(String timeOut)`. So on login, call `insertRow()` which will create a new record (i assume that's the case?). When logout, call `updateRow()` to update the created record with your timeout.

Comment: Definitely it is.